# The tag '...' does not exist in XML namespace '...' but it appears in IntelliSense

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

In a .xaml file of one of my projects I have the following line:

```
<UserControl 
...
xmlns:AuxView="clr-namespace:MySoftware.Resources.Aux_Views;assembly=MySoftware.Resources">
...
```

And then the line:

```
<AuxView:Loading_Simple/>
```

Which produces the error, and thus does not compile the project:

> Error 2   The tag 'Loading_Simple' does not exist in XML namespace
>   'clr-namespace:MySoftware.Resources.Aux_Views;assembly=MySoftware.Resources'.
>   ...

However, the **MySoftware.Resources assembly is referenced**, it **appears in the IntelliSense**, and **other projects make use of this without problems**.

Also the Target Framework of the projects is .NET Framework 4 (**not Client Profile**).

I have tried **cleaning** and **rebuilding** the solution with no results.

I also tried **creating another project from scratch**, with the same code, and the problem persists.

I have no idea of what to do further. Any ideas? I use Visual Studio 2010.

Thanks.

---

**Edit: Now it magically worked. And apparently, I have changed nothing relevant. This sounds like a VS bug. I will keep the question opened if someone finds the real reason.**

Comment: Other projects use it without problems but if you create another project from scratch the problem persists?

Comment: Yes, there are old projects that reference the `<AuxView:Loading_Simple/>` and use it normally. When I said I  created from scratch was because I thought it was some issue with the project configuration, so I created a new one, created all the same .cs and .xaml files of the old one one by one and pasted the same code on them.

Comment: Why do you do a bunch of stuff and then test?  Create a new project with just that user control. Then add stuff one at a time and test.

Comment: Good idea, but apparently it won't be necessary because now it magically worked. And apparently, I have changed nothing. This sounds like a VS bug. But I will keep the question opened if someone finds the real reason.